# Virtual Directories and GET Requests

Tags: jquery, .htaccess, content-management-system, directory, virtual

Suitable Code for enabling virtual directories below specific parent directory and sending url to existing parent directory as GET request but remain showing Virtual Directory as URL?

I have a CMS I am developing, but I want to setup so that under a specific directory, for example, a Product section, I want it so I don't have to render pages for all products and instead the site instead of going to a 404 saying that directory does not exist, it loads the parent Product section with the appropriate GET data (url of actual requested directory) but still show the Requested Directory as if it exists.

For Example: http://www.example.com/products/store/general/support_anchor/
Translated:  [domain]/[existing directory]/[virtual directories sent to (existing directory) as GET requests] still shows as For Example URL.

Thanks!

Comment: Advice: Remove that last line.

Comment: I'm sure asap you will get a lot of comments here with your last line.